# JQuery icon looks incorrect on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

**This works correct on desktop browsers** but on all iPhone browsers I have this bug(did not test on android phones)

Normally you can fully see the white, down looking arrow sign inside the circle, on iPhone as you can see in the image there is only a little piece of it is visible.

Any ideas how can I fix this? I use jQuery mobile and referencing image files locally from

```
css/images
```

folder, and my head scripts are like this

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

and html is

```
        <select id="langoptions">
            <option class="langCH" value="0">Chinese</option>
            <option class="langEN" value="1">English</option>
        </select>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you POST HTML code of this button?

Comment: Try to create a jsfiddle ONLY with select and css and verify on your iPhone. Do you use any float styles before the select?

Comment: @Simon yes there are some floats used in css file for page title, menu title..etc is that a problem?

Comment: To check if it's floats causing the issue (I don't think it is), put this in a document ready wrapper... `$("*").css("float", "none");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was using an image file belonging to jQuery 1.3.1 while my css was 1.2.0

Downloaded the 1.2.1 legacy zip file, used the correct sprite and it is fixed. Those two sprites actualy have the same icons but one of them is slightly larger in length, so causing to center-off the images.